# Некорректно форматируется дата из строки

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Корректно отображается только год. В чем ошибка?

```
String stringBirthday = String.format("%s %s %s", ourPerson[3], ourPerson[4], ourPerson[5]);
System.out.println(stringBirthday);
// получаем строку вида 23 11 1950
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM YYYY", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date birthday = null;
try {
    birthday = format.parse(stringBirthday);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println(birthday);
//получаем дату вида Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 MSK 1950
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С маленько буквы год надо писать же:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Дока по [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).